# Android: how run other app in small window

Tags: android, multi-window

I saw lots of apps that can run ANY installed application in small window.
I write my own.

Now I can run any app in Multiscreen mode:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, ExampleAccessService.class));
        //wait for completion, unfortunately waitForIdle doesn't applicable here
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("APP_NAME");
        LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ActivityOptions ao = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0 ,100,100);
        ActivityOptions bounds = ao.setLaunchBounds(rect);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent, bounds.toBundle());
        finish();
    }
}
```

And service for enable multi-window:

```
import  android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;
import      android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
public class ExampleAccessService extends AccessibilityService{

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Boolean res = performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN);
        Log.i("GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN", res.toString());
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onServiceConnected();
    }

}
```

But now it runs NEAR other apps, not in the new window.
I know that is possible to run in SMALL window ANY installed app.
What I missed to do it?

Oh, I solve!
Just don't need ExampleAccessService

Comment: consider adding your edit as an answer instead, as users with the same problem might easily miss that last sentence in your question and think that there hasn't been a solution provided for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solve! Just don't need ExampleAccessService